# How to align vertically span text (floated) to bottom

Tags: html, css

I current have this result:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

**m** and **s** should be aligned to the bottom.

**My code:**

```css
.right-timer-area {
  width: 128px;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffa000;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered {
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.right-timer-area .timer-sm {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-timer-area">
  <span class="timer-centered">
    <span class="timer-big">15</span>
    <span class="timer-sm">m</span>
    <span>-</span>
    <span class="timer-big">45</span>
    <span class="timer-sm">s</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

But it didn't work. Are there any ways of solving, without changing `.right-timer-area` (it's centered inside other `div`) and without `table-layout`?
If yes, then how?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmads0rp/1/

Comment: you can try using subscript tag <sub> </sub>

Comment: Please See my  answer Sir..

Comment: Why you not using `sub` tag ?

Comment: @Maddy sub is not positioning element directly on one bottom line

Comment: Please Check it My answer Now Sir@brabertaser1992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you have added `float: left;` to `.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span`. This overrides `display: inline-block;` and means that `vertical-align` has no effect. To obtain the desired result make the following changes:

- Remove `float: left;` from `.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span`
- Change `.right-timer-area .timer-sm` to `.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered .timer-sm` to make it more specific. This ensures that it overrides rules set in `.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span`
- Add `vertical-align: sub;` to `.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered .timer-sm`
- Remove the whitespace between the `span`s in HTML either by removing the actual space, reducing the `font-size` of `timer-centered` to `0`  or by using the comment trick

```css
.right-timer-area {
  clear: right;
  width: 128px;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffa000;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered {
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered .timer-sm {
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}
.right-timer-area .fontsize {
  font-size: 0;
}
.right-timer-area span.fontsize span {
  font-size: 36px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-timer-area">
  <span class="timer-centered">
    <span class="timer-big">15</span><span class="timer-sm">m</span><span>-</span><span class="timer-big">45</span><span class="timer-sm">s</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="right-timer-area">
  <span class="timer-centered fontsize">
    <span class="timer-big">15</span>
    <span class="timer-sm">m</span>
    <span>-</span>
    <span class="timer-big">45</span>
    <span class="timer-sm">s</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="right-timer-area">
  <span class="timer-centered">
    <span class="timer-big">15</span><!--
    --><span class="timer-sm">m</span><!--
    --><span>-</span><!--
    --><span class="timer-big">45</span><!--
    --><span class="timer-sm">s</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: in my code i couldn't remove spaces, and get extra space, that's why i'm using floating

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I've added some extra methods you could use to remove whitespace. Hope at least one of them are useful!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: table-cell` and remove `float: left` from `.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span`:

```css
.right-timer-area {
  width: 128px;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffa000;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered {
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span {
  display: table-cell;/*change to table-cell*/
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.right-timer-area .timer-sm {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-timer-area">
  <span class="timer-centered">
        <span class="timer-big">15</span>
  <span class="timer-sm">m</span>
  <span>-</span>
  <span class="timer-big">45</span>
  <span class="timer-sm">s</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this -

```css
.right-timer-area {
  /*width: 128px;*/
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffa000;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
  display: table;
}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered {
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-row;

}
.right-timer-area > span.timer-centered span {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
}
.right-timer-area .timer-sm {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-timer-area">
    <span class="timer-centered">
        <span class="timer-big">15</span>
        <span class="timer-sm">m</span>
        <span>-</span>
        <span class="timer-big">45</span>
        <span class="timer-sm">s</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: m and s are not on one bottom line